# JavaScript SVG rotation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm writing an SVG manipulation library and I'm at the point where I'm trying to implement the transformations. After a bit of reading I figured I'd tap into the underlying `SVGMatrix` object and use it's transformation methods. So far I have the `translate` and `flip` methods implemented and working as I'd expect them to, but I can't get the rotation methods to work. Well, not quite, the `rotate` works and I can see the object I'm testing with (`rect`) rotate around my screen wildly. What I can't seem to make work is the `rotateFromVector` method. So far, I've tried chaining it right after the `rotate` method, but it's not working as expected (I want the `rect` to rotate around its' center).

I'm guessing that perhaps the `cx` and `cy` values that are passed to `rotateFromVector` have to be somehow pre-computed, I can't just pass in the raw value?

I'd appreciate it if someone can take a look at the code below and let me know what I'm missing. The JavaScript is compiled down from TypeScript, in case anyone is wondering about why it is the way it is.

```
var Matrix = (function () {
    function Matrix(element) {
        this.ctm = element.getScreenCTM();
        this.element = element;
    }
    Matrix.prototype.apply = function () {
        this.element.setAttribute("transform", "matrix(" + this.ctm.a + "," + this.ctm.b + "," + this.ctm.c + "," + this.ctm.d + "," + this.ctm.e + "," + this.ctm.f + ")");
    };
    Matrix.prototype.flip = function (x, y) {
        if (x) {
            this.ctm = this.ctm.flipX();
        }
        if (y) {
            this.ctm = this.ctm.flipY();
        }
        this.apply();
    };
    Matrix.prototype.rotate = function (a, cx, cy) {
        if (a === void 0) { a = 0; }
        this.ctm = this.ctm.rotate(a);
        if (cx && cy) {
            this.ctm = this.ctm.rotateFromVector(cx, cy);
        }
        this.apply();
    };
    Matrix.prototype.translate = function (x, y) {
        if (x === void 0) { x = 0; }
        if (y === void 0) { y = 0; }
        this.ctm = this.ctm.translate(x, y);
        this.apply();
    };
    return Matrix;
})();
```

Comment: I find the best way to visualize a transform matrix is in its component parts. The matrix a,b,c,d,e,f ; (a,b) is the direction you want `X` to move, (c,d) is the direction you want `Y` to move, and e,f is where you want the origin. The X and Y vectors also have scale. To convert a angle into a vector is (cos(angle),sin(angle)) to scale a vector multiply it by the scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out in the end. It turned out that I can't pass in a degree directly, it has to be converted to a radian first and then the calculations have to be done. So, here's the correct code below:

```
var MatrixInfo = (function () {
    function MatrixInfo(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        if (a === void 0) { a = 1; }
        if (b === void 0) { b = 0; }
        if (c === void 0) { c = 0; }
        if (d === void 0) { d = 1; }
        if (e === void 0) { e = 0; }
        if (f === void 0) { f = 0; }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
        this.e = e;
        this.f = f;
    }
    MatrixInfo.parse = function (element) {
        var ctm = element.getScreenCTM();
        return new MatrixInfo(ctm.a, ctm.b, ctm.c, ctm.d, ctm.e, ctm.f);
    };
    return MatrixInfo;
})();

var SvgBase = (function () {
    function SvgBase() {
    }
    SvgBase.prototype.attr = function () {
        var args = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            args[_i - 0] = arguments[_i];
        }
        if (typeof (args[0]) === "object") {
            for (var _a = 0, _b = Object.keys(args[0]); _a < _b.length; _a++) {
                var k = _b[_a];
                this.attr(k, args[0][k]);
            }
            return this;
        }
        if (args[1] === null) {
            this.element.removeAttribute(args[0]);
            return this;
        }
        if (!args[1]) {
            return this.element.getAttribute(args[0]);
        }
        if (args[0] === "href") {
            this.element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", "#" + args[1]);
        }
        else {
            this.element.setAttribute(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        return this;
    };
    return SvgBase;
})();

var SvgMatrixBuilder = (function (_super) {
    __extends(SvgMatrixBuilder, _super);
    function SvgMatrixBuilder() {
        _super.call(this);
        this.mI = new MatrixInfo();
    }
    SvgMatrixBuilder.prototype.apply = function () {
        this.attr("transform", "matrix(" + this.mI.a + "," + this.mI.b + "," + this.mI.c + "," + this.mI.d + "," + this.mI.e + "," + this.mI.f + ")");
    };
    SvgMatrixBuilder.prototype.refresh = function (element) {
        this.element = element;
        return this;
    };
    SvgMatrixBuilder.prototype.rotate = function (a, cx, cy) {
        var radian = .017453292519943295 * a, cos = Math.cos(radian), sin = Math.sin(radian);
        if (!cx && !cy) {
            var eI = ElementInfo.parse(this.element);
            cx = eI.width / 2 + eI.iX;
            cy = eI.height / 2 + eI.iY;
        }
        this.mI.a = cos;
        this.mI.b = sin;
        this.mI.c = -sin;
        this.mI.d = cos;
        this.mI.e = -cx * cos + cy * sin + cx;
        this.mI.f = -cx * sin - cy * cos + cy;
        this.apply();
    };
    SvgMatrixBuilder.prototype.translate = function (tx, ty) {
        if (tx === void 0) { tx = 0; }
        if (ty === void 0) { ty = 0; }
        this.mI.e = tx;
        this.mI.f = ty;
        this.apply();
    };
    return SvgMatrixBuilder;
})(SvgBase);
```

Answer (score 0):

`rotateFromVector()` is not what you want to be using here.  It isn't doing what you think it is.  It is for another purpose.

If you want to rotate around point (cx,cy), then the steps you need to perform are:

- move the origin to cx, cy - ie. translate(cx, cy)
- rotate
- move the origin back to where it was - ie. translate(-cx,-cy)

So your rotate function should be:

```
Matrix.prototype.rotate = function (a, cx, cy) {
    if (a === void 0) { a = 0; }
    if (cx && cy) {
        this.ctm = this.ctm.translate(cx, cy);
    }
    this.ctm = this.ctm.rotate(a);
    if (cx && cy) {
        this.ctm = this.ctm.translate(-cx, -cy);
    }
    this.apply();
};
```

Also, you should be able to optimise your `apply()` function a bit.

```
Matrix.prototype.apply = function () {
    var svg = this.element.ownerSVGElement;
    var tf = svg.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(m);
    this.element.transform.baseVal.appendItem(tf);
};
```

This should be more efficient than setting the attribute with a stringified version of the matrix.